# ng-pattern is not working for number input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement input number field which will allow positive or negative numbers.

I have used `"/^0|[1-9]\d*$/"` regex expression for ng-pattern.
But it is not working.For character input it is not showing any error.
I have pasted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TgxcJ/).

#### Update

I don't want to make this field as required.I just want only number validation(charters are not allowed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. The pattern `/^0|...$/` is interpreted as `/(^0)|(...$)/`. So, your pattern will accept any string that either begins with `0` (no matter what follows) or ends with any digit in [1-9] (optionally followed by any number of digits).
   The correct pattern is: `/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/` (note that `\d` will match more characters than [0-9], e.g. arabic digit symbols etc).
2. The input elements of type number are handled in the following way by the browser:
   If their content is not a valid number, then their `value` property is set to `''`.
   Thus, entering `1w3` will cause the `value` to be an empty string, so then pattern will not be applied.
   You should use an input element of type `text`.
3. (This is not directly related to your question, but I noticed in your fiddle, you were using `<form>.<input>.$invalid`, instead of the (probably) intended `<form>.<input>.$valid`.
   `$invalid` is a **[property of the `FormController`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController#properties_$invalid)** only.)

---

Based on the above, your code should look more like this:

```
<input type="text" name="price_field" ng-model="price"
       ng-pattern="/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/" />
```

(For accepting negative numbers as well, change `ng-pattern` to `/^(0|\-?[1-9][0-9]*)$/`.)

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/63mwL)**.

<sub>(**UPDATE:** The demo has been updated to illustrate the differences between number- and text-fields and between different patterns.)</sub>

Comment: How to validate minimum and maximum value if i use text instead of number?

Comment: @Wilson: You can't unless you either "embed" it in the pattern or use a custom directive.

Comment: You can use myForm.input.$error.number in newer versions of angular. It is working fine for me. see docs for input[number].

Answer (score 2):

Why do not use `required` with `min`. So we can write:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
        <input type="number"
               ng-model="price" 
               ng-init="price=0"
               name="price_field"
               min="0"                  
               required
              >
        <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.required ||
                       myForm.price_field.$error.min">Not a valid number!</span>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgxcJ/4/)**</kbd>

Howevewr if you still want to use pattern, remove `type="number"`. I'm not sure but sounds like type `number` has own pattern, this is a reason why it doesn't work.

Here is 2nd Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgxcJ/5/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

used htm5 pattern for input  number only

```
<input type="number" name="country_code" pattern="[0-9]" >
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp